# Gitlab CI services access docker runner

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm running Gitlab CI pipeline with docker-runner and linked service:
`.gitlab-ci.yml`

```yaml
image: maven:3-jdk-11
prometheus_tailer:
  stage: test
  services:
    - name: lossuperktos/stats-prometheus
      alias: prometheus
  script:
    - mvn test
```

`lossuperktos/stats-prometheus` Dockerfile:

```docker
FROM prom/prometheus
ADD prometheus.yml /etc/prometheus/
EXPOSE 9090
```

It loads configuration from `prometheus.yml`:

```yaml
global:
  scrape_interval:     15s
  evaluation_interval: 15s

scrape_configs:
  - job_name: queue_monitoring
    scrape_interval: 5s
    scrape_timeout: 5s
    metrics_path: /metrics
    static_configs:
      - targets: [ 'http://localhost:9091' ]
```

So basically I need two-directional communication, I can access `lossuperktos/stats-prometheus` within app by alias "prometheus" and it works fine. Problem starts when prometheus service is trying to access `localhost:9091`. I know it cannot work, because of different networks but I cannot figure how can I solve this issue. Could someone point me in right direction?

Comment: Hope this helps to resolve your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64452521/unable-to-access-xxx-could-not-resolve-host-gitlab-ci-cd-pipeline/64462166#64462166

Answer (score 1):

> I need two-directional communication

## Default links do not allow you to talk to build container

By default, service containers cannot establish connections to job containers.

Your best bet would be to use docker-compose within your job instead.

As an alternative, if you're running the application on `localhost:9091` in a container, AND you're using the [`docker:dind` service](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html#use-the-docker-executor-with-the-docker-image-docker-in-docker) for running `docker`, services can reach the containers you run with exposed ports using the alias of the docker dind daemon service.

This works because the application would be reachable through a service container, the docker daemon service running the application container prometheus wants to scrape.

As a hack you can even set the alias of the dind service to `localhost` though, I wouldn't recommend it. You'll probably want to change the scrape config to the hostname.

See: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/services/#connecting-services

## Use docker network per-build

Alternatively, if you configure your docker executor to [create a docker network for each job](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/docker.html#create-a-network-for-each-job) the job container is resolvable by using the `build` alias; the hostname is assigned by GitLab.

So you could set the scrape config to look at the host `http://build:9091` and make sure the image has `EXPOSE 9091` set in the dockerfile.